# This requires the 'enhanced-enums' language feature to be enabled

Tags: flutter, dart

I just upgraded my Flutter SDK but I am still not able to use the enhanced-enums.

```
$ dart --version
```

prints

```
Dart SDK version: 2.18.0-109.0.dev
```

This is my code:

```dart
enum Foo {
  bar(0),
  baz(1),

  final int i;
  const Foo(this.i);
}
```

I get the following errors:

> This requires the 'enhanced-enums' language feature to be enabled.

> Expected to find '}'.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two problems here.

1. Update your Dart SDK version constraint in `pubspec.yaml` file to use the new Dart `2.17.0` version

   ```
   environment:
     sdk: ">=2.17.0 <3.0.0"
   ```

   Then run `flutter pub get` command
2. You must end your enum with a semicolon `;` and not with a comma `,`

   ```dart
   enum Foo {
     bar(0),
     baz(1); // <-- Replaced "," with ";"

     final int i;
     const Foo(this.i);
   }
   ```

Comment: I am still getting error even after updating `>=2.17.0 <3.0.0` in `pubspec.yaml`

Comment: @KartikGarasia Make sure you're updating your project's `pubspec.yaml` not the packages one and don't forget to run `flutter pub get` after that.

Comment: The change of syntax from ending with a trailing comma to a semi-colon was unexpected for me, but it makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Do `flutter clean` before `flutter pub get`.

Comment: @RolandPuntaier `flutter clean` is not required.

Comment: But I just moved Dart version, and the error message did not go away by only `flutter pub get`. That is why I googled and came across this. So in case it does not work: Do a `flutter clean` first. That helped for me. My situation was with Xcode. There are many situation. I don't think you can say that it is not required ever.

Answer (score -1):

Closing and reopening IDEA helped me.
In my case the IDEA is VSCode.